# WildFly 10.1.0 remote connection to standalone ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: jboss, jndi, activemq-artemis, wildfly-10, message-driven-bean

I'm trying to configure WildFly 10.1.0 to use MDB's with context of the remote ActiveMQ Artemis server. Problem occures when trying to use injected remote JMSContext - naming exception(looking for transaction). Steps I did:

1. WildFly `standalone-full.xml` configuration: (only added entries are listed)

- Output Socket Binding

```xml
<socket-binding-group>
    ...
    <outbound-socket-binding name="remote-artemis">
        <remote-destination host="192.168.56.10" port="61616"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Messaging configuration

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
    <server name="default">
        <remote-connector name="remote-artemis" socket-binding="remote-artemis"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="remote-artemis" entries="java:/jms/remoteCF" connectors="remote-artemis" user="foo" password="bar"/>
    </server>
</<subsystem>
```

- Naming Configuration - where external context is configured

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
    <bindings>
        <external-context name="java:/remote/artemis/" module="org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq" class="javax.naming.InitialContext" cache="true">
            <environment>
                <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
                <property name="java.naming.provider.url" value="tcp://192.168.56.10:61616"/>
            </environment>
        </external-context>
    </bindings>
    <remote-naming/>
</subsystem>
```

2. Standalone Artemis ActiveMQ configuration (server is running on linux as a service)

- added `foo=bar` user, with admin rights
- JAAS Security is used
- added queue name="example.queue" to JMS broker

3. Usage

Sample Consumer:

```java
@MessageDriven(name = "MessageConsiumer", activationConfig = {                
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionFactoryLookup", propertyValue = "java:/jms/remoteCF"),     
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="user", propertyValue="foo"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="password", propertyValue="bar"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "java:/remote/artemis/dynamicQueues/example.queue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge") })
public class MessageConsiumer implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) message;
            System.out.println(msg.getText());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Sample Producer:

```
public class MessageProducer {
    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("java:/jms/remoteCF")
    @JMSPasswordCredential(userName = "foo", password = "bar")
    private JMSContext context;
    
    @Resource(lookup = "java:/remote/artemis/dynamicQueues/example.queue")
    private Queue queue;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void send() {
        TextMessage msg = context.createTextMessage();
        msg.setText("Sample text");
        context.createProducer().send(queue, msg);
    }
```

It seems that JMSContext and destination Queue is injected properly(debugged). Error occures at runtime, on first JMSContext usage i.e.:

```java
TextMessage msg = context.createTextMessage();
```

Naming exception is popping out, looking for `comp/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry`.

Is that up to standalone ActiveMQ Artemis transaction configuration? Or maybe is that WildFly's side? Any ideas what might that be?

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry -- service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry
    at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.deployment.injection.InjectedJMSContext.lookup(InjectedJMSContext.java:134)
    at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.deployment.injection.InjectedJMSContext.getTransactionSynchronizationRegistry(InjectedJMSContext.java:109)
    at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.deployment.injection.InjectedJMSContext.isInTransaction(InjectedJMSContext.java:98)
    at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.deployment.injection.InjectedJMSContext.getDelegate(InjectedJMSContext.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.deployment.injection.JMSContextWrapper.createProducer(JMSContextWrapper.java:66)
    at testr.messaging.MessageProductioner.sendThat(MessageProductioner.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.handleInvocation(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:103)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry -- service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
    at org.apache.activemq.jndi.ReadOnlyContext.lookup(ReadOnlyContext.java:223)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.deployment.injection.InjectedJMSContext.lookup(InjectedJMSContext.java:132)
    ... 74 more
```

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/266937

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/250745

Comment: http://www.fiorano.com/forum/general-discussion-4/how-to-lookup-a-connectionfactory-using-external-jndi-in-wildfly/msg928/#msg928